# empty space displaying once we click on button

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, product-view, review

we have review tab in product page [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/under-water-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html) , please search using CTRL + F for "review"

[image]

once we click on "Be the first to review this product", it displaying like this , means complete design is spoiled

[image]

```
<div class="form-add">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Write Your Own Review') ?></h2>
    <?php if ($this->getAllowWriteReviewFlag()): ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getAction() ?>" method="post" id="review-form">
        <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form_fields_before')?>
        <h3><?php echo $this->__("You're reviewing:"); ?>
            <span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductInfo()->getName()) ?></span>
        </h3>

        <div class="fieldset">
            <?php if( $this->getRatings() && $this->getRatings()->getSize()): ?>
                <h4><?php echo $this->__('How do you rate this product?') ?> <em class="required">*</em></h4>
                <span id="input-message-box"></span>
                <table class="data-table review-summary-table ratings" id="product-review-table">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their are two things, your layout for review form page is 2columns-right (col2-right-layout) which must be 1column (col1-layout)

and in **styles.css**

@ line no 6469  make following changes

```
#customer-reviews {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: thansk for support.

Comment: updated please check and confirm

Answer (score 1):

Actually,

http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/under-water-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html and

http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/review/product/list/id/150/#review-form

are loaded from TWO different template files (.phtml)

So apply changes of

```
/app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

(PRODUCT VIEW PAGE) to

```
/app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/template/review/view.phtml
```

(REVIEW FORM PAGE)

Comment: thansk for support.

Answer (score 0):

below css fixed issue for me

```
.review-product-list .col2-right-layout .col-main {
    float: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
}
```